# In VSCode, How can I enable Angular/Backbone/jQuery intellisense for a project without a package.json?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

right now I'm stuck trying to get code autocompletion for a few popular libraries like BackboneJS, Angular and jQuery. The problem, is that the preferred method of enabling this support by the VS Code official docs is unavailable to me (using package.json)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

I followed the steps to the letter and created a `jsconfig.json` file that looks like this;

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "lodash",
            "angular",
            "jquery",
            "underscore"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "content/**/*.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules/*",
        "node_modules",
        "**/tmp/*",
        "tmp",
        "**/temp/*",
        "temp",
        "**/bin/*",
        "bin",
        "**/build/*",
        "build"
    ]
}
```

However, I still am not able to see angular or backbone js autocompletion. Also, it might not help I'm not using commonjs modules (not using `require('angular')` or `import 'backbone'`) beacuse the current project is built with AMD module system using require js (`require(['modulename], function(module) {...})`)

Any ideas to how I can somehow get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be difficult since VS Code's intellisense [does not understand AMD style modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6942).

You may be able to use [`/// <reference ...>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) imports and then annotating each the `require` functions with the proper types:

```
///<reference types="jquery" />
///<reference types="react" />

require(['jquery', 'react'], function (
    /** @type {$} */jq,
    /** @type {React} */react
) {
   ...
})
```

[This feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377) would also help you if it is implemented